# Dynamic Javascript tag as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append one tag which is in FOR loop. But they are not working same as HTML tags.

Here is what i did in JavaScript

```
var numberOfImages=allpost.page.attachments.length;
$(".GalleryAppend").append('<ul class="gallery" id="Gallery"></ul>');
for(var i=0;i<=numberOfImages;i++){
    var blogpost = '<li><a href="'+allpost.page.attachments[i].url+'" rel="external"><img src="'+allpost.page.attachments[i].url+'" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "/></a></li>';
    $(".gallery").append(blogpost);
    $(".loading-text").remove();
    $("html").trigger("refresh");
}
```

And i want to make it something like this.

```
<ul class="gallery" id="Gallery">
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/images/photo-gallery/big/6.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.example.com/images/photo-gallery/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "/></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/images/photo-gallery/big/7.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/photo-gallery/thumbs/7.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "/></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/images/photo-gallery/big/8.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/photo-gallery/thumbs/8.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "/></a></li>
</ul>
```

One thing is added at the bottom. If you can suggest something on the based of that.

```
  (function(window, PhotoSwipe){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var
            options = {},
            instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );
    }, false);
}(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

When i try your code i got this error "no image to passed".

[image]

Because if i am not making it so, my gallery is not working. I tried many combinations.

Can someone suggest any thing related to this?

Thank you! (Advance)

Comment: Check the console, are you getting any errors? Saying "It's not working" is too unspecific.

Comment: you probably be getting some error in console, post tat error

Comment: your $('.gallery') means nothing to jquery during your append to it.

Try:

$(document).find(".gallery").append(blogpost);

Comment: Its working, but again i can not make the image zoom. When it zoom it looks something like this http://www.vbought.com/Pankhida-app/photo-gallery.html

Any suggestion why my Jquery/Javascript is not working?

Comment: Gurami: I tried, it looks same. No different. When i am clicking on the image, its just opening the image without zoom.

Answer (score 0):

You are making DOM changes in jQuery (Client Side) and making page refresh using:

```
$("html").trigger("refresh");
```

How can that retain it. That's the reason it doesn't work. You need to re-enable the handlers, by calling them again. Say, I guess you are using Lightbox kind of plugin. So, you need to technically replace:

```
$("html").trigger("refresh");
```

With the following:

```
$(lightBoxElement).lightbox("destroy");
$(lightBoxElement).lightbox("enable");
```

That's a pseudo code. Replace with your actual destroy and enable function to re-enable for dynamically added items.

---

#### Try #2

Do something like this!

```
var numberOfImages=allpost.page.attachments.length;
$(".GalleryAppend").html("").append('<ul class="gallery" id="Gallery"></ul>');
for(var i=0;i<=numberOfImages;i++){
    var blogpost = '<li><a href="'+allpost.page.attachments[i].url+'" rel="external"><img src="'+allpost.page.attachments[i].url+'" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "/></a></li>';
    $(".gallery").append(blogpost);
    $(".loading-text").remove();
    var options = {},
       instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );
}, false);
}
```

Comment: I am using PhotoSwipe. I tried your way. But not working

Comment: There's no way you can destroy. Just looking at their API, doesn't seem good! But it is a nice concept.

Comment: I edited, some information and added some jquery into my question. You can see. If that helps you to understand better.

Comment: @user3201500 Why have you complicated yourself like this? `:O`

Comment: Are you using a lot of `#Gallery`? Coz, `id`s are supposed to be unique and can be used only once!

Comment: No i use it only once.

Comment: I tried new updated answer also. But i am getting one error i am updating in answer

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: If you want i can give you the zip file, where i am trying this.

Comment: Okay... send me a link. :)

Comment: Do you have GMail? I will send you a test mail and you can remove that comment.